# Does Kubernetes reuse containers from previous cron jobs?

Tags: kubernetes

Should I worry about leaving my container dirty? For example if I create files every time it's run, should I delete these files at the end of the job?

Answer (score 1):

Every file you create will be deleted when the job finishes unless you mount a persistent volume, that way you can share data between subsequent runs of the same job.

So, you shouldn't worry to delete the files you created unless they are bigger than ~40GB

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Storage: Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/)*

> On-disk files in a container are ephemeral, which presents some problems for non-trivial applications when running in containers. **One problem is the loss of files when a container crashes. The kubelet restarts the container but with a clean state.** (this applies to newly created `Jobs` too).

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/)*

> A Job creates one or more **Pods** and will continue to retry execution of the Pods until a specified number of them successfully terminate.

Comment: What's so special in 40Gb size?

Comment: There is a limit on the allocatable space for cointainers without persistent volumes, it varies on each node configuration

Comment: So, what's so special in 40Gb? Why not 20 or 41?